# How many tools we have given each tool is in two toolboxes?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm reviewing combinatorics and can't find a right approach to the following problem:

There are $n$ toolboxes. Any pair of toolboxes shares one kind of tool. Thus, each kind of tool is in two toolboxes. How many kinds of tools are there?

The first thing that came to my mind was thinking in just two boxes with n tools. Thus, given the fact that each kind of tool is in two boxes, there are n tools. But as you increment the number of toolboxes it gets messy because there's no way to determine exactly how many tools are in each toolbox. For example, with 3 toolboxes we can have one empty and the other two with both pairs. Then I got to think of it as a version of the handshake problem, but I'm still not sure about a correct approach. Thanks for the help.

Comment: “Each kind of tool is in two tool boxes.” That doesn’t follow. For instance, if every toolbox has only a screwdriver...

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion that any tool must be in at most $2$ toolboxes is false.

For example, when $n=7$ and with tools $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ you can get toolboxes with:

$$\{1,4,7\}\\
\{1,2,5\}\\
\{1,3,6\}\\
\{2,3,4\}\\
\{2,6,7\}\\
\{3,5,7\}\\
\{4,5,6\}$$

Any two toolboxes contain exactly one tool in common. Each tool is in $3$ toolboxes.

This is the “finite projective plane of order $2.$”

For general $n$ find a prime $p$ with $p^2+p+1\geq n$ and construct the finite projective plane with $p^2+p+1$ points(tools) and lines(toolboxes,) and then choose $n$ of the lines. Then each toolbox will have exactly $p+1$ tools, and a total of up to $p^2+p+1$ different tools.

(Technically, you can choose $p$ to be a prime power.)

Answer (score 0):

> Any pair of toolboxes shares one kind of tool.

No tool kind is in three toolboxes.  Each pair of toolboxes has at exactly one kind of tool shared in the pair.

> each kind of tool is in two toolboxes

No tool kind is in only one toolbox.

Consequence: If a kind of tool is present, it is present in exactly two toolboxes.  And any such pair of toolboxes has exactly one tool kind in common.

So, how many ways are there to select $2$ out of $n$ toolboxes?